# Bootstrap overlapping images thumbail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

So I'm using the Bootstrap Thumbnail grid system, everything is looking ok apart from the images seem to be overlapping and I can't work out why? I've attached an image too.

When I'm hovering over the images the images in the middle are overlapping each other? I don't know if I'm being completely stupid or it's a bootstrap default I just can't win at?

[image: As you can see their overlapping, i just need a 3px margin between each of the images but they're overlapping?]

```
    HTML

    <div class="top-header"class="page-header">
    <h1>Smile Board</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image01.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image02.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image03.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image04.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image05.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image06.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image07.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image08.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image01.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image02.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image03.png" alt="">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/image04.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
        </div>


CSS

    body {
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaina', cursive;

}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
  width: 1170px;
}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: #EFEC86;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 1130px;
}

.top-header {
  width: 1130px;
  background-color: #EFEC86;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 1290px;
}

.sub {
  background-color: #EFEC86;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width:calc(150% - 10px);
  margin:0 16px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: #EFEC86;
}

.row {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: code seems right.in bootstrap on hover there is nothing like that so image get overlapped.If its occurring then try remove any bg-color or border on hover for image.and also don't scale image size on hover.if its work fine then ok ,otherwise share jsfiddle with test code.

Comment: I've done that and it's still not working

Comment: if you give jsfiddle test,so we can analyse the issue

Comment: what do i do just upload it?

Comment: ok i've done it, but how do i show you it?

Comment: just visit https://jsfiddle.net/ and add you code here and save the code,after then share that url here

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/umk8bLwt/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script> hope that works

Comment: refer url for your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/bpqk2Lx1/1/

Comment: after using bootstrap you are using width and height for your thumbnail.its not required.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so so much :) Do you know if I wanted it mobile responsive what I would do?

Comment: I am happy that it's work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not adding margin when you are hovering each item. Just add margin on the `.thumbnail` class when it is hovered so that it will not destroy your other item

Comment: That's still not working :( makes they topple over each other

Comment: Have you tried to remove the margin in your `.thumbnail` class even it is not in the hovered state? I think the reason why it will overlayed the other divs it is because of the margins.

Comment: One more question, to make it responsive on a mobile, what would I do?

Comment: If you want to make it responsive on a mobile device dont fixed that width and height of your `thumbnail` class or else you can use @media queries for that.